# Binding brush color to properties in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, controltemplate

I am trying to make a CustomControl that derives from Button, which simply shows as a colored rectangle. I want to have two properties on my control that I can set, which specify the normal color (ColdColor), and another color that will be used when the mouse is over the control (HotColor).

I can't figure out how to get the binding set up between the brush color and the control properties. This is my code:

Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TestCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestCustomControl}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Name="MyBorder">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <!-- This works: -->
                        <!--<SolidColorBrush Color="Green" />-->

                        <!-- This doesn't work: -->
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding ColdColor}" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!-- This works: -->
                                    <!--<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" To="Red"  Duration="0:0:0.2"/>-->

                                    <!-- This doesn't work: -->
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" To="{TemplateBinding HotColor}"  Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

TestCustomControl.cs:

```
public class TestCustomControl : Button
{
    static TestCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestCustomControl)));
    }

    public Color HotColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(HotColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HotColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HotColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HotColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HotColor", typeof(Color), typeof(TestCustomControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Color()));

    public Color ColdColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ColdColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColdColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColdColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColdColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColdColor", typeof(Color), typeof(TestCustomControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Color()));
}
```

Usage in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<my:TestCustomControl ColdColor="#FF0000AF" HotColor="#FFFF00AF"/>
```

EDIT: To say that "doesn't work" means that the TestCustomControl is entirely transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no obvious problem (afaik), I would change this piece of code:

```
UIPropertyMetadata(new Color())
```

to

```
UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.White)
```

and see if its the 'new Color()' that's the problem

**EDIT** -

if the above didnt work, try changing this

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding ColdColor}" />
```

to this

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
    Path=ColdColor}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work, i.e. the TestCustomControl is entirely transparent.

Comment: Thanks a bunch: That halfway works! Meaning that it works for the brush specified in the Border.Background element. The ColorAnimation does nothing; the control continues to be painted with ColdColor. EDIT: I applied the same change to the animation, of course, changing the Path to HotColor.

Comment: OK, I did a test where I used an eventtrigger on the Border element to animate to HotColor, and this works. So it appears that the remaining problem lies with using binding from within the VisualState element. Any ideas on that?

Comment: No idea on the Visual State issue - sorry

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help, I'll mark this as answered and start a new thread specific to the other issue.

Answer (score 0):

The visual state manager has a related limitation:  it can not animate properties set with a binding.  So you are just trying to do something that can't be done.

What you can do is duplicate the elements and use opacity to do the transition.  The following shows how you would do this with the VSM and opacities:

Given a custom control TwoColorBox with dependency properties

```
 Color ColorOne
 Color ColorTwo
```

and with visual states:

```
 ColorOne
 ColorTwo
```

The following control template will do as you want without transparency bleed-through

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type view:TwoColorBox}">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ColorStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="ColorOne"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="ColorTwo">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="borderTwo">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border 
            x:Name="borderOne" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush 
                    Color="{Binding ColorOne, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
        </Border>
        <Border 
            x:Name="borderTwo" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush 
                    Color="{Binding ColorTwo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```